# Sorting json results by 10 max results

Tags: jquery, json, shopify

Below is a snippet of something i just fixed up, i added true / false in the returned json results for available (in stock products) so it only shows in stock products however its not working great. Its showing like a max of 6 or 7 but in same cases only show 2 so it is limiting some how... example if i search iphone it now returns 2 items then shows See all results (61) but cant see where its doing this.... would want to show 10 ideally.

WHOLE CODE

```
$(function() {
  // Current Ajax request.
  var currentAjaxRequest = null;
  // Grabbing all search forms on the page, and adding a .search-results list to each.
  var searchForms = $('form[action="/search"]').each(function() {
    // Grabbing text input.
    var input = $(this).find('input[name="q"]');
    // Adding a list for showing search results.
    var offSet = input.position().top + input.innerHeight();
    $('<ul class="search-results"></ul>').css( { 'position': 'absolute', 'left': '0px', 'top': offSet } ).appendTo($(this)).hide();    
    // Listening to keyup and change on the text field within these search forms.
    input.attr('autocomplete', 'off').bind('keyup change', function() {
      // What's the search term?
      var term = $(this).val();
      // What's the search form?
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      // What's the search URL?
      var searchURL = '/search?type=product&q=' + term;
      // What's the search results list?
      var resultsList = form.find('.search-results');
      // If that's a new term and it contains at least 3 characters.
      if (term.length > 1 && term != $(this).attr('data-old-term')) {
        // Saving old query.
        $(this).attr('data-old-term', term);
        // Killing any Ajax request that's currently being processed.
        if (currentAjaxRequest != null) currentAjaxRequest.abort();
        // Pulling results.
        currentAjaxRequest = $.getJSON(searchURL + '&view=json', function(data) {
          // Reset results.
          resultsList.empty();
          // If we have no results.
          if(data.results_count == 0) {
            // resultsList.html('<li><span class="title">No results.</span></li>');
            // resultsList.fadeIn(200);
            resultsList.hide();
          } else {
            // If we have results.
            $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
              console.log(item.available);
              if(item.available == true) {
                var link = $('<a></a>').attr('href', item.url);
                link.append('<span class="thumbnail"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" /></span>');
                link.append('<span class="title">' + item.title + '</span>');
                link.wrap('<li></li>');
                resultsList.append(link.parent());
              }
            });
            // The Ajax request will return at the most 10 results.
            // If there are more than 10, let's link to the search results page.
            if(data.results_count > 10) {
              resultsList.append('<li><span class="title"><a href="' + searchURL + '">See all results (' + data.results_count + ')</a></span></li>');
            }
            resultsList.fadeIn(200);
          }        
        });
      }
    });
  });
  // Clicking outside makes the results disappear.
  $('body').bind('click', function(){
    $('.search-results').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thinkg the ajax returns max 10 results and then i filter them if they are available or not and in this case 2 out of the 10 are so shows the 2 but not sure what to do to show the 10 after the available true

Comment: So the json results are returning 9 results, 2 of them are instock hence why showing 2....  cant seem to work out where that is though in the code to add available conditions.

Comment: `// If we have results.
            $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
              console.log(item.available);
              if(item.available == true) {...` This bit is making sure only "available" results are displayed. The others are simply never rendered to the page. If you want to display all of them just remove the `if(item.available == true) ` test

Comment: I did notice that the json only returns 9 results 7 of which are out of stock so i guess i need to adjust the json.liquid file... i made a question for that here but little stuck on that as well. its new for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594034/shopify-json-array-returning-results-but-some-empty-results