# Shopify JSON array returning results but some empty results

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I am wanting to pull back only results that are available but it is returning in the json response null,null,null,result, result for example. Here is the code:

```
{% capture results %}
  {% for item in search.results %}
    {% assign product = item %}
    {% if product.available == true %}
      { 
        "title"    : {{ product.title | json }},
        "url"      : {{ product.url | within: product.collections.last | json }},
        "thumbnail": {{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'thumb' | json }},
        "available": {{ product.available | json }}
      }
    {% endif %}
    {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
```

Anyone know what i would need to do to not return the null results but only the available true ones and exclude the available(false)

It returns 9 results, 7 of which are not available and would show 2 but need it to return 9 available not 2 out of the 9 if you know what i mean.

Comment: Its based from here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/store/enable-autocomplete-for-search-boxes but need to just bring back available products

Comment: i don't know liquid markup...where is search.results coming from? Is it a database query? Maybe you should not return them at all in the original query results.

Comment: Its returned by json from another file... no database queries as its a sass product you see. if you look at that URL it shows how it pulls back from the json file which returns 10 items which guess is the product. I am doing some digging.

Comment: if you just want to return all of them populated then I would guess you should remove `{% if product.available == true %}` - at the moment any with available==false don't get their properties populated. Then in your UI you can decide which to display

Comment: Yea but then still have the issue with it display 10 in stock products as the array only returns 10 and 2 of those are only in stock so would again only show 2 - get what i mean?

Comment: see the other question. I explained how to make it display all of them

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do here:

1. You can create a search app outside of Shopify. This app will fetch all the products, check each product for availability condition and return the search results in arrays of 10, 20, 30 etc products, which you can store locally the session if you intend to do pagination.
2. For each product that is available on your store, add a tag ***istock*** (In Stock) and for those that are not available have a tag ***ostock***. While searching, just append ***+istock*** to the search query. It'll always return only the products matching the search term and with the tag "istock".